# switch box red wire connected to white?

Tags: electrical, switch, neutral, multiway-switch

i'm installing smart switches, and found the neutral in another area so i assumed it'd be in all the switch boxes. Well not these two. It's a 3 way switch, and in the back of it there are white wires connected to red wires. Would this be the neutral? I also heard the neutral wire could be behind the switch box.

house built 2000
3 way switch

any recommendations on verifying a neutral or where to find one?

[image]

Comment: Never, never, never grab neutrals from random places.  Only use a neutral **if it is in the same cable as one of the wires going to the switch**.   In some cases that means you are forced to fit the smartswitch at one end or the other, and in a few cases, it can't be done at all.  Note that white wires are not necessarily neutral, for instance if a white wire goes to a plain switch, it is not a neutral because plain switches don't use neutral.  If it goes to a bundle of non-white wires, it is not a neutral because **all** neutrals must be white. (But not all whtites are neutral).

Comment: Can you get us some better quality photos of the situation inside the box?